# argoCD not able to sync even after detecting changes

Tags: argocd

I’m trying to setup an argoCD application, with following syncPolicy

```
syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
    - CreateNamespace=true
    - Prune=false
    - Replace=false
```

ArgoCD is able to detect new changes and I can see that in the UI, but its not syncing automatically - I need to manually click on sync button to sync it. Any idea where I’m going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just set default automated option? You can investigate which option could be a cause of the issue.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally disabled autosync/selfHeal in the application via UI? 
What does the output of `kubectl get application <APPNAME> -o jsonpath='{ .spec.syncPolicy }'` say?